# Sorting a column based on user input

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

Please refer to the code below. I´m trying to sort the content of my sheet based on the cell input on the `Range("AD2")`. The problem sits on the line `key1:=rng_sort` which I believe is being called in a wrong way.

What I want to do is change the column that is sorted based on the condition that is chosen on the cell
`Range("AD2")`. On that cell i´ve a data validation list as seen below:
[image]

If `Range("AD2") = "Event"`i want to sort the column I. If it equals "Vo" i want to sort the column J.

Any Idea what i might be doing wrong?

Thank you.

```
Sub sortEvent()

Sheets(1).Activate ' activate sheet(1)

Dim n As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim h As Integer
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Dim ng_sort As Range
        
        Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row ' guarda o indice da ultima linha com conteudo da coluna I. Mesmo havendo vazios identifca a ultima linha
        Length = Range(Range("I10"), Range("I" & Lastrow)).Rows.Count ' dimensão da coluna O ate a ultima celula com conteudo começando na O6
        
For firstrow = 1 To Length ' loop na coluna O
            If Range("C2").Offset(firstrow, 0).Interior.Color = RGB(68, 114, 196) Then
                Exit For
            End If
Next firstrow

If Range("AD2") = "Event" Then
        rng_sort = Range("I1")
    Else
        rng_sort = Range("J1")
End If
            
n = 0
j = 1
        
        For i = 1 To Length ' loop na coluna I
            If Range("C2").Offset(firstrow + i, 0).Value <> "" Then
                n = n + 1
            Else
                Range(Range("C2").Offset(firstrow + j, 0), Range("C2").Offset(firstrow + j + n - 1, 0)).EntireRow.sort key1:=rng_sort, order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
                j = j + n + 1
                n = 0
            End If
        Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show a representative example of your data (with sensitive information removed), along with the type of contents that might be entered into `AD2`. And also an explanation of what you mean by *working great except ...* would be useful in helping us help you.  Take a look at the Help pages for [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi thank you for the advise. I changed the question to make it more clear. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have `Option Explicit` set at the beginning of your module, else you would have seen your problem.

Go to Tools/Options and set the Option to always require variable declaration.  I don't know why MS doesn't make that the default.

You have

```
Dim ng_sort As Range
```

but in your code, you show

```
rng_sort = Range("I1")
```

Since `rng_sort` was never declared, it will be used as a variant and contain the contents of `Range("I1")`, not the range object.

Had you declared `Option Explicit`, this would have been flagged as a typo; and without the `Set` keyword, you would have received a runtime error 91, and been able to figure this out for yourself.

Try:

```
If Range("AD2") = "Event" Then
        set rng_sort = Range("I1")
    Else
        set rng_sort = Range("J1")
End If
```

I have not tested your code, as you did not provide any data example, but you definitely need to `Set` a range object.